# URL Rewrite rules appear to be redirecting instead of rewriting

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, redirect, url-rewrite-module

I am using IIS URL Rewrite 2.0 module to create a URL that always points to the latest version of my app. I have configured it as follows:

```xml
<rule name="Latest" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^latest(.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="1.1{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

The intention is that if something goes to `/latest/*` then all of the URLs are rewritten as `/1.1/*`. For example `/latest/index.html` should become `/1.1/index.html`.

This is working when I request a file, for example:

```
/latest/index.html - works
/latest/js/app.js - works
```

However this does not work:

```
/latest
```

Since `index.html` is the default document, I would expect this to rewrite to `/1.1/index.html`, but in fact it seems to do a *redirect*. For example, if I type the following in the browser address bar:

```
http://<domain>/latest
```

and press ENTER, it changes to:

```
http://<domain>/1.1
```

as if redirected. It still works, but I don't want the URL to change (hence why I'm using `Rewrite` rather than `Redirect`). Any idea why? Is there something wrong my rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely the problem you're experiencing:

> [IIS generates courtesy redirect when folder without trailing slash is requested](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/298408/en-us)

*(Although that article is about IIS6, IIS7+ behaves in the same way and it seems you can't disabled this behaviour.)*

Add a rule before your existing one that matches just `/latest` (no trailing slash):

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Latest1" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^latest$" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="1.1/" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Latest2" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^latest(.*)" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="1.1{R:1}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

There's probably a more elegant way, that does what it says on the tin.

You may need to do a hard reload of the page because your browser may cache the redirect, you can always test in "incognito mode" which never saves permanent redirects between sessions.

Comment: Thanks, it appears to work to a degree, except all of the resources referenced in the index.html appear to be loaded from the wrong URL. For example, if I go to /latest then a <script src="js/app.js"> will request '~/js/app.js' rather than '~/latest/js/app.js'. Although, I think this is to be expected since it'll consider 'latest' to be a file rather than a path..?

Comment: Disregard the previous comment - I think Salman A explained and resolved this too.

Answer (score 3):

When you request the URL `/latest` your rules rewrites it to `/1.1`. Since `/1.1` matches an existing directory instead of a file, IIS responds with a courtesy redirect [as described here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/298408). IIS uses the rewritten URL since it cannot see the original URL.

---

Instead of serving same content through two URLs (`/latest` and `/latest/`) I would suggest that you emulate the same behavior through your rules. If the requested URL is `/latest` it should first redirect to `/latest/` then rewritten:

```xml
<rule name="Latest: force trailing slash" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^latest$" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="latest/" redirectType="Found" />
</rule>
<rule name="Latest: rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^latest/(.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="1.1/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. I've included this along with Kev's answer and it's now behaving how I'd like. Thanks!